# Android - Firebase calls duplicates Map

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an application in Android Studio with Firebase where I am using the map to show different things. The first time the user enters the MapsActivity a alertdialog pops up with some information. My problem is that when the "OK" button is pressed the application automatically duplicates the activity and the duplicated activity is ran. When i press the back button I can go back to the "original" activity again. I think it is because of the multiple Firebase calls. Are there any fix to this?

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            if (marker.equals(m1)) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                dialog.setTitle("Bus stop");
                dialog.setMessage("Do you want your kid to get picked up here?");
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
                dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        database.child("Addresses").child(m1.getTitle()).child("name").setValue(m1.getTitle());
                        database.child("Addresses").child(m1.getTitle()).child("time").setValue(m1.getSnippet());
                        database.child("Addresses").child(m1.getTitle()).child("users").child(userId).setValue(username);
                        database.child("User").child(userId).child("address").setValue(m1.getTitle());

                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
```

Comment: Where in your code are you creating a new actvity?

Comment: Thats the problem. I am not creating a new activity. It is duplicating by itself (unwanted)

Comment: The attached code is the code that duplicates the activity